# Why does Swift 2.2 not support fixed sized arrays, maybe swift 3.0 support?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

I'm trying to create a game for iPhone (it's simple, just to sharpen my skills), and I've noticed that Apple has yet to show any support for fixed sized arrays (i had a huge issue with keeping track of my enemies I'm spawning and it would have helped a lot to have a fixed array). Does anyone know why they're not supported? Or if they will be supported in Swift 3.0?

Comment: Fixed-sized array is not listed in https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution, so no it won't be supported in 3.0.

Comment: Just start a thread on swift-evolution ;) say what you want and why and let the discussion start :)

Comment: Do you just want an array that isn't growable or are there other features you're interested in?

Comment: just a non-growable array, just like java has something like "int [] myArray = new Int [20];", this is the only thing I've found that i really would like. that and C style for loops..but ill just get used to the new syntax they're pushing :)

Comment: `var myArray = [Int](count: 20, repeatedValue: 0)` gives you an array of size 20 initialized with zeros. You can then index it in the normal way to access values or assign new values.

Answer (score 1):

You are not writing C, don't carry the C's baggage with you. Arrays in Swift falls into 2 types: constant array, which is fixed-length and fixed value, you can't modify anything; or variable-length and variable value. Each array knows its length (`arr.count`), so you don't need a separate variable to keep track of it.

As for `for` loop, the more I write Swift, the less I used this:

```
for var i = 0; i < arr.count; i++ { ... }
```

And the more I used these:

```
for item in arr { ... }
for (index, item) in arr.enumerate() { ... }
arr.forEach { ... }
arr.map { ... }
```